# JQuery Assign differents width for <li> elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've an html list :

```
<ul>
  <li> first element </li>
  <li> second element </li>
  <li> third element </li>
  <li> 4th element </li> 
  ....
</ul>
```

with jquery, i want to assign for first `<li>` a width equals 10% and for others `<li>` (to second until last) the rest of width divided by numbers of numbers `<li>` (90% / 5 for example)

I must exclude the `<li>` exist un sublist

How to do this with JQuery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use a function inside `css()` and assign the right width using that method just once

```
var li = $('#outermostlist > li');
li.css('width', function(i) {
    return (i === 0)? '10%' : (90 / (li.length - 1)) + '%'; 
})
```

example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hzHUn/3/

(Firebug view for 4 elements and 1 nested list)

[image]

Of course pay attention to the result obtained by `90 / (li.length - 1)`: in some circumstances the sum of all values may be greater than `100%`, and this could be not exactly what you want: so if this is the case, just be sure to round the result in some way to the  previous lower integer (e.g `~~(90 / (li.length - 1)))`;

Comment: when i tru to apply this, i obtein the widht equals length of text, i dont know why

Comment: please setup a fiddle with a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and update your original question with a link

Comment: I must also exclude the child of li (sublist), because the number of li, i obtein also all <li> exist in sublist

Comment: Just apply a `class` or an `id` to the outermost `<ul>` and use the immediate children selector to target the right `<li>`, e.g. `var li = $('#outermostlist > li');`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var $lis = $('ul > li');
$lis.eq(0).css('width', '10%');
$lis.slice(1).css('width', (90 / ($lis.length - 1)) + '%');
```

Comment: Damn you're good. Disappointed you missed the chance to merge the two last lines though ;)

Comment: with this solution you need to call twice the css() method, not really necessary

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

**JS**

```
$("#myul li:eq(0)").width("10%").css("background", "yellow");
$("#myul li:gt(0)").width("90%").css("background", "red");
```

note that the bg color is just to better visualize the result

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/U9tcV/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to set `width` for first `li` in CSS and the rest using jQuery like below:

**CSS:**

```
li:first-child{
    width: 10%;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemWidth = Math.floor(90/($('ul > li').length - 1)); //using Math.floor to make sure it doesn't go beyond 100%
    $('ul > li:not(:first)').css('width', itemWidth + '%');
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/edyCU/)

**EDIT:** IE <=6 doesn't support `first:child` CSS, so the below script line can be used in jQuery to style the first `li` element.

```
$('ul > li:first').css('width', '10%');
```

Comment: i cant use first-child because the website must be compayible with all version of IE

Comment: first-child is supported in IE7+. Do you want to support IE 6 and less? [Support Chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/)

Comment: Yes, it must support IE and less

Comment: @tchiko: Ok, I have edited my answer to include styling for the first element also using jQuery. But honestly if all have to be done through jQuery then Fabrizio Calderan's answer is better.